# PHP Sort array by multiple third dimension values

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to find a way to sort this array based on **more than one** of the third level properties.

So, I'd like to sort the top level array first by **`latency`** and then by **`load1minavg`**, and then by **`packetloss`**.

Can anyone explain to me how I would go about doing this? I've looked at the **`usort`** function and can't seem to make it work the way I need it to. I'm aware of an **`array_multisort`** function that I feel could be used here, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to use it effectively.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

An example of the array I'd like to sort (**the array is dynamic and the values are likely to change**)

```
$servers = [
    [
        'bnd' => [
            'comp' => 'ifo',
            'rate' => 5
        ],

        'stat' => [
            'load1minavg'  => 15,
            'latency'      => 12,
            'packetloss'   => 8
        ]
    ],

    [
        'bnd' => [
            'comp' => 'lto',
            'rate' => 18
        ],

        'stat' => [
            'load1minavg'  => 20,
            'latency'      => 96,
            'packetloss'   => 11
        ]
    ],

    [
        'bnd' => [
            'comp' => 'lto',
            'rate' => 13
        ],

        'stat' => [
            'load1minavg'  => 5,
            'latency'      => 18,
            'packetloss'   => 31
        ]
    ]
];
```

Comment: what about items which does not contain some field used  for sort?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't follow exactly what you're saying. Could you rephrase it?

Comment: it's my bad, i misread.

Comment: Look there  - https://eval.in/788052